# Why can't NewDocumentEnvironment have {t!} in its signature?

Tags: xparse

The [xparse manual](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf) (2018/02/21) states for optional arguments:

> t
>
> An optional *<char>*, which will result in a value `\BooleanTrue` if *<char>* is present and `\BooleanFalse` otherwise. Given as `t<char>`.

If I use the signature: `{st! O{t}d()}` then compilation aborts with:

```
 Argument of \somemacro has an extra }
```

If I change the `!` into a `?` or a `+` everything works as expected.

I can imagine that special characters like `%`, `#`or `\` are forbidden. But an innocent exclamation mark? Can this be a bug? Or is the exclamation mark not so innocent? Is there a list of (dis)allowed chars?

Comment: please always provide a small complete example that shows the problem. Are you using a babel language that gives `!` special definition?

Comment: Thanks for the hint David. Indeed I test the package I develop with a lot of examples. And one of them concerns different languages. And I happen to load babel turkish, which is the culprit. All the same: Is there a list of forbidden chars?

Comment: there can be no list, if I make `\catcode\`\a=\active` then you would not be allowed to use `a` so _any_ character can be made to fail and conversely if you make `%` catcode 12 it could be made to work.

Comment: OK. Can I assume that "normally" the "usual" special chars are not allowed, and the others are? Please, change your comment into an answer, that I can accept.

Comment: It would be invalid also with `babel-french`. Likewise, `-` is invalid for `babel-czech`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use a babel language (or other package) definition that makes characters active they may or may not work here, depending on the specific definition that has been given to the character. In the case of babel you can use

```
\shorthandoff{!}
```

to make `!` safe and then `\shorthandon` later to give it its language-specific definition.